# how does Multithreading in GPUs work?

Tags: multithreading, gpgpu, gpu

How does a GPU handle multithreading ??

In CPUs for example there will be independent copies of the Register File for each thread. But with large register files as in GPUs that will be impossible. So how does GPUs handle threads ?? 
Do they fit them in the same register file ? What if some registers are used in more than one thread ? How does that work ?

Comment: If number of total threads are a multiple of core number(n.thread = n.core*X), then the threads are issued in wavefronts like 1 thread after another and pipelines are more occupied than single thread version(n.thread = n.core) They share the same register file at least in my hd7870. So, if you add even more threads, you should lessen the usage of registers per thread. Maybe it can start spilling them to main gpu-memory. In a Nbody program I used 51200 threads for 1280 cores, each thread was using more than 20 float variables. For non-scalar (vector) type architectures, this can limitmaxthreads

Comment: If gpu pulls a thread's variables from main memory, this would make it very slow. Register file can be 20-100 times of main memorys bandwidth. Maybe different in bigger cached cards like tesla.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NVIDIA GPUs have 1-4 warps schedulers per streaming multi-processor (SM). Each SM warps scheduler has a local register file. Warps are allocated to a warp scheduler and registers are allocated from the register file. The allocation lasts the for the lifetime of the warp. On each cycle each warp scheduler picks an eligible warp (not stalled) from it's active warp list and issues 1-2 instructions (CC <= 2.0 can only single issue).

This differs from SMT CPUs which have separate copies of some resources, but share the front end and execution paths. Intel CPUs supporting HyperThreading can dispatch instructions from both hardware threads each cycle depending on arbitration of the dispatch ports.